# How can I write this equation with Libreoffice formula?

Tags: libreoffice

How can I write this equation with LibreOffice formula? At first, I do not know how to write this symbol of Hilbert space, another thing is, I do not see the option to put a limit in the symbol of direct sum like this picture. Anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: This is definitely one of those *"It's all Greek to me"* moments.

Comment: You can try to ask on [Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/) for faster response.

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/154822/how-can-i-write-this-equation-with-libreoffice-formula/

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix so lets ask Terdon >:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
H = oper ♁ from M = 0 to L H_M
```

Comment: I tried it and it only halfway worked. Maybe it's because you haven't listed all the steps, so please add the steps to your answer.

Comment: See the link in comments and add it into the q with reference ;)